# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'colour' in true (related function return type)

Tags: typescript

So I have the following code in typescript:

```
let a: unknown = true;

if(hasColour(a)) {
    console.log(a.colour);  // I want to use a.colour after checking a does have the colour property
}
```

So I create a function to determine if I have the colour property:

```
function hasColour (obj: any) : boolean {
    return !!obj &&
    "colour" in obj &&
    typeof obj == "object" 

}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'colour' in true.

A resolution to this is to specify, instead of boolean as the return type:
`obj is { colour: string }` like this:

```
function hasColour (obj: any) : obj is { colour: string } {
    return !!obj &&
    "colour" in obj &&
    typeof obj == "object" 

}
```

**Why** does this work? **Shouldn't hasColour return a true/false?** Why does it work with `obj is { colour: string }`  as a return type?

Comment: Your code still throws a runtime exception. You perhaps want: `typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null && 'colour' in obj` instead

Comment: zerkms, this actually works: function hasColour (obj: any) : obj is { colour: string } {
    return !!obj &&
    typeof obj == 'object' &&
    'colour' in obj 
}  whether I use apostrophes or double quote marks. ... the question is why does it work ... why not boolean as a return type? after all, i am testing to see if the object has that property (yes) or not (no)

Comment: It does not work, it still throws a runtime exception. You also better stop using `any` and use `unknown` instead.

Comment: @nos actually not: it's `'colour' in obj` where `obj` is boolean that throws.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between...

```
function hasColour (obj: any) : boolean {
    return !!obj &&
    typeof obj == "object" &&
    "colour" in obj
}
```

...and...

```
function hasColour (obj: any) : obj is { colour: string } {
    return !!obj &&
    typeof obj == "object" &&
    "colour" in obj
}
```

...is that the second construct is a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). A type guard will narrow your `unknown` type to `{ colour: string }`. Within the scope of the `if` using the type guard, the compiler will assert the existence of the `colour` property.

The first construct just returns a `boolean`. The compiler can assert nothing from it, because it does not know that in the function you are actually doing a type check. With a type guard you explicitly tell the compiler it should assert the type.

Comment: The problem is that this type guard throws, it simply is wrong.

Comment: @zerkms Yes. :)

Comment: Now if `any` was changed to `unknown` it would be ideal :-)

Comment: @zerkms: In the original code the argument is of type `unknown`. That's what I'm referring to.

Comment: `function hasColour (obj: unknown)` --- type guards with unknown arguments is a way to go: let a compiler help you infer a type, not ignore its discoveries.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, but analysing a bit closer my first example why should  `'colour' in obj` throw an error if the method is NOT constructed as a typeguard? Why not just simply return false?

Comment: Ok, I guess the problem was the two conditions should be reversed: `typeof obj == "object" &&` (first) and then
   `"phoneNumber" in obj` (secondly, only if the previous condition is fulfilled)

Comment: So now that I got it to work with both `boolean` and `obj is { colour: string }` as return types ( by just reversing those conditions - see my previous comment), why is it necessary to use `obj is { colour: string }` after all?

Comment: Read the answer, then you'll know.